# Encapsulating one-line AppleScript with C system() call using fgets() and echo

Tags: c, macos, scripting, terminal, applescript

If I have condensed an AppleScript into one line, how can I encapsulate it to run in an `echo` `system` call from a C program? All the formatting I have tried result in errors: (single quotes, double quotes, various brackets, etc...)

In case it isn't clear, I have a C program that uses `fgets()` to capture input. When I try to echo in a system command, like `echo ' && foo bar && $? '` it generally works. But if I want to `echo` in an AppleScript directly, I can't seem to get the formatting down. Any ideas?

FWIW here is what I'm trying:

`echo ' && "osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'do script "foo bar"' -e 'end tell'" && $?'`

The above example echoes everything contained within the single quotes and "prints" it, but doesn't execute it. I have tried many variations on quotes, etc, to no avail. Also, between `osascript ... 'end tell'` works when run directly in the terminal.

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

Here is a snippet of the C code:

```
    char comment[80];
    char cmd[120];
    fgets(comment, 80, stdin);
    sprintf(cmd, "echo '%s %s' >> reports.log", comment, now());
    system(cmd);
```

**Edit Two... changed title to be more accurate**

Comment: Could you post a runnable example rather than `foo bar`?

Comment: Sure. Pretty much any bash script will work *it seems*... `echo ' && pwd && $? '` is a simple one that works through my C program. Similarly `echo && pwd && $?` works directly into the terminal.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Oh, and for the AppleScript something like this will work in the terminal: `echo && osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'do script "pwd"' -e 'end tell'` ... obviously I can't get it to work with echo through the program

Comment: How are you including that in your C code?

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, in the first example, it is made successful for the C program by encapsulating it in single quotes... this does not work in the AppleScript version.

Comment: `system("echo && osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\"' -e 'do script \"pwd\"' -e 'end tell'")`?

Comment: @JoshCaswell it is used through `fgets()`... see edit

Answer (score 3):

Ok! Based on your comments, I would rewrite your question something like this:

> #### How to trick `system("echo %s")` into running AppleScript?
>
> I'm trying to push the limits of `system()` to understand why it is
>   important to be careful with its use in C. This sample program is
>   presented in a book on C:
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
>
> char* now() {
>     return "yyyy-mm-dd";
> }
>
> int main() {
>     char comment[80];
>     char cmd[120];
>     fgets(comment, 80, stdin);
>     sprintf(cmd, "echo '%s %s' >> reports.log", comment, now());
>     return system(cmd);
> }
> ```
>
> I can "echo out" of the program and execute most bash scripts with the
>   program by typing `' && pwd && '`. Now I want to figure out how to do
>   something similar, but by using AppleScript instead of bash. I’m
>   trying this:
>
> ```
> ' && "osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'do script "foo bar"' -e 'end tell'" && '
> ```
>
> The `osascript ... 'end tell'` command works when run directly in the
>   terminal, but it’s not executing properly. I have tried many
>   variations on quotes, etc, to no avail.

Then, my answer would be the following:

---

To make it easier to debug exactly what command is being run, let’s echo the command to the terminal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* now() {
    return "yyyy-mm-dd";
}

int main() {
    char comment[80];
    char cmd[120];
    fgets(comment, 80, stdin);
    sprintf(cmd, "echo '%s %s' >> reports.log", comment, now());

    /* for debugging */
    printf("executing %s\n", cmd);

    return system(cmd);
}
```

Now let’s try it out:

```
$ gcc -c prog.c -o prog
$ ./prog
' && osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'do script "date"' -e 'end tell'" && '
executing echo '' && osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'do script "date"' -e 'end t yyyy-mm-dd' >> reports.log
```

Huh! It somehow got cut off as `end t` instead of `end tell'" && '`. Wait, how big is the input buffer? *80* characters? That’s the problem! The AppleScript command you’re trying is syntactically correct, but is too long for the input buffer and is getting chopped off.

Eliminating all whitespace and using a [little-known bash feature](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings) to embed the newlines, I can just barely squeeze that AppleScript into 77 characters:

```
'&&osascript -e$'tell application "Terminal"\ndo script "date"\nend tell'&& '
```

Since the 80-character buffer needs a null-terminator at the end, it really only has room for 79 characters. So with this particular AppleScript command you can run shell commands in terminal up to 6 characters long…

---

My answer to what I thought was your original question—how to call a multi-line AppleScript from C—remains:

---

Command-line arguments can have newlines in them. You can run an entire AppleScript from bash like this:

```
$ osascript -e '
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "date"
end tell'
```

bash pauses waiting for the closing `'`, and then passes the whole script as a single argument.

You can do something similar in C, just with a bit more quoting:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    system("osascript -e '\n"
            "tell application \"Terminal\"\n"
            "   do script \"date\"\n"
            "end tell'\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The flexibility that `fgets()` offers is rather convenient--I can pass a number of bash arguments with the same program. While reworking my program to format  input and then send it as a `system()` call is definitely a possibility, I was hoping for a simple solution in encapsulating AppleScript in `echo`, as I am able to do for `bash` with `echo`... Do you know of a way to capture AppleScript with `echo` as I can for bash commands?

Comment: I’m sorry, but I’m having trouble understanding exactly what you’re trying to do. Are you just trying to append the `comment` from `fgets()` and a timestamp to `reports.log`? For that you can do `FILE* reports = fopen("reports.log", "a"); fprintf(reports, "%s %s\n", comment, now()); fclose(reports);` and skip `system()` and `echo` entirely.

Comment: No, I'm trying to push the limits of `system()` to understand why it is important to be careful with its use in C. This exercise is presented in a book on C. I can "`echo` out" of the program and execute most bash scripts with the program, and I want to figure out how to do something similar, but by using AppleScript instead of bash. Thus the various examples of bash working and AppleScript not working. **The basic question**--at this point--is how can I encapsulate AppleScript into the `fgets()` via terminal input so I can echo into the terminal and execute AppleScript.

Comment: This is clearer: the book has an exercise to "abuse" `system()` to understand how to be careful with its use in C programming. I can "echo out" of the program when it asks for input via `fgets()` by using something similar to one of the examples above. However, I can only do this successfully with bash commands. I am curious if it can be done with AppleScript, which necessitates incapsulating the AppleScript into fgets(), system(), echo etc. I cannot get an echo to execute an AppleScript in this fashion, but echoing an AppleScript can be done directly into the terminal from `~$` ...

Comment: ... so I am thinking it is simply a syntax error, because I have to capture the "echo out" with single quotes, and I think this conflicts with the use of single quotes in AppleScript. At least, that is my guess.